# copying data out of a huge production table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

The company I'm working for has some huge log/journal tables that are being written to every 10 seconds or so with transactions.  I'd like to copy out a lot of the data in this table and delete it from that table because about 75% of the old data could be put in an archive table or something, but if I do this wrong and the table gets locked up it would be a disaster.

In a previous question a guy came up with something like this, I'd like to know that this wouldn't screw everything up, is the nolock hint enough to keep me safe and all the writes working just fine?  If not, what should I do?

```
set identity_insert newtable on
DECLARE @StartID bigint, @LastID bigint, @EndID bigint
select @StartID = max(id)+1
from newtable

select @LastID = max(ID)
from oldtable

while @StartID < @LastID
begin
set @EndID = @StartID + 1000000

insert into newtable (FIELDS,GO,HERE)
select FIELDS,GO,HERE from oldtable (NOLOCK)
where id BETWEEN @StartID AND @EndId

set @StartID = @EndID + 1
end
set identity_insert newtable off
go
```

Comment: This is great except what's your plan for DELETING the old records?  Not really a way to do that without some sort of locking happening.

Comment: Yeah, I clarified the question a little, so what's the best way to delete the old records while not getting in the way of normal db operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extreme caution in generating your list is probably overboard, but you will want to run a batch delete.

For the `INSERT`, you probably don't need the `WHILE` loop.  For the `DELETE`, though, I would use something like this (tune the batch size to your needs):

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
   DELETE TOP (10000) o
   FROM OldTable o
   INNER JOIN NewTable N
      ON o.id = n.id
   IF @@ROWCOUNT < 10000 BREAK;
END
```

This will `DELETE` 10k records at a time as long as there are records to delete.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past with a large table, archiving and deleting records in batches. Basically it looked like your code but with a "begin tran" and a "commit tran" inside the while loop. I then backed-up, truncated and shrunk the log.

Comment: If he is worried about contention I wouldn't do a transaction since that would lock the table :)

Comment: Thanks JNK, so you would recommend that I do the copy first then do the delete?  Anything else I need to worry about?  Sorry, I'm just super paranoid, but I think that seems like it would work.

Comment: Yes, I would say order of operations is: 1 - Copy, 2 - Verify, 3 - Delete

Answer (score 0):

One option is to partition the table by hour (assuming you have a `DATETIME` column in the table that defaults to `GETDATE()` on every insert). Having the partitions allows you to perform maintenance (drop, copy, etc.) on the older partitions without affecting the current one.

Comment: He's concerned about locking the table long enough to select and you are suggesting adding a partition scheme?  I'm pretty sure that will cause some locking as well...

Comment: @JNK yes but that could be part of a future planned downtime